# create a custom translatable resource file in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

how i can create a custom **translatable** resource file in Android? Like strings.xml but my own.

I know that i can create `temp.xml`. and fill it like that

```
<resource>
    <item name="some_name" type="string">Some name example</item>
    ...
</resource>
```

But don't know how to translate it.

Comment: `values-es/strings.xml` is for Spanish, for example

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, but i use strings.xml for app usage - button text, placeholders ect. Now i need to enable translation for custom .xml file

Comment: I don't know what you mean by custom xml. What you've shown in your question can be added to strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

just like this

```
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
 <translate
     android:fromXDelta="50%"
     android:toXDelta="50%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%"
     android:toYDelta="100%"
     android:duration="5000"
 />
```

Comment: I don't think you understood. Translate languages, not an animation